# Can I use Regex in Rails .where()?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a menu that shows the first letter of various artists:

`A B C D E F ...`

It basically is a way to filter many artists by first letter of name.

The problem some begin with a symbol, a number, or anything other than `[a-z]`.

So I want it to be

`# A B C D E F ...`

But how do I go about making that work with my where clause?

```
filter_letter = (params[:letter] =~ /[a-z]/i ? params[:letter] : "something_here" )

@artists = Artist.where("name LIKE ?", "#{filter_letter}%")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using mysql, you can leverage it's support for regular expressions. You'll want to switch to the `RLIKE` operator and adjust your operands accordingly.

For example, using your existing structure, you could use the following

```
filter_letter = (params[:letter] =~ /[a-z]/i ? params[:letter] : "[^a-z]" )
@artists = Artist.where("name RLIKE ?", "^#{filter_letter}")
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html for more information. Note in particular that mysql regular expressions are not case sensitive, so you don't need to worry about that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your "something here" can be restated as "the set of all first characters of artists' names which are not in A-Z."

```
symbolic_artists = Artist.where("SUBSTRING(name, 0, 1) NOT IN (?)", 'A'..'Z')
symbols = symbolic_artists.map(&:name).map(&:first)
filter_letter = (params[:letter] =~ /[a-z]/i ? params[:letter] : symbols
@artists = Artist.where("SUBSTRING(name, 0, 1) IN (?)", filter_letter)
```

I hope the () works correctly, but if it does not we can easily fix it. The point is to use SUBSTRING not LIKE, and to express Ruby ranges as SQL IN clauses.